# Tags deleting other widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

Python tkinter snake game (not very experienced with python). When the apple is meant to be made, nothing is shown on the canvas. Then when you move the body grows after a few more moves. This amount of moves before growth goes up by 1 each time an apple is made. I think this is because of the tags on the snake blocks made and deleted but I don't know how to fix this. Is there any other cause and how could I fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window=Tk()
window.title("snake")
window.geometry("600x600")
can=Canvas(window,height=600,width=600,background="white")
can.pack()

num=1
x3=100
y3=100
decide=3
etch_len=10
etch_wid=10
body_len=2
apple_x1=0
apple_y1=0
colour=["black"]

def move_up(self):
    global x3
    global y3
    global num
    global apple_x1
    global apple_y1
    global body_len
    if x3==apple_x1 and y3==apple_y1:
        body_len=body_len+1
        apple_make(self)
    num=num+1
    x=str(num)
    can.create_line(x3,y3,x3,(y3-etch_len),width=etch_wid,fill=colour[0],tag=x)
    y3=y3-etch_len
    remove_last(self)


def move_down(self):
    global x3
    global y3
    global num
    global apple_x1
    global apple_y1
    global body_len
    if x3==apple_x1 and y3==apple:
        body_len=body_len+1
        apple_make(self)
    num=num+1
    x=str(num)
    can.create_line(x3,y3,x3,(y3+etch_len),width=etch_wid,fill=colour[0],tag=x)
    y3=y3+etch_len
    remove_last(self)


def move_left(self):
    global x3
    global y3
    global num
    global apple_x1
    global apple_y1
    global body_len
    if x3==apple_x1 and y3==apple_y1:
        body_len=body_len+1
        apple_make(self)
    num=num+1
    x=str(num)
    can.create_line((x3-etch_wid),y3,x3,y3,width=etch_wid,fill=colour[0],tag=x)
    x3=x3-etch_len
    remove_last(self)


def move_right(self):
    global x3
    global y3
    global num
    global apple_x1
    global apple_y1
    global body_len
    if x3==apple_x1 and y3==apple_y1:
        body_len=body_len+1
        apple_make(self)
    num=num+1
    x=str(num)
    can.create_line(x3,y3,(x3+etch_wid),y3,width=etch_wid,fill=colour[0],tag=x)
    x3=x3+etch_len
    remove_last(self)


def remove_last(self):
    global num
    global body_len
    i=num-body_len
    x=str(i)
    can.delete(x)


def apple_make(self):
    global apple_x1
    global apple_y1
    apple_x1=random.randint(10,590)
    apple_y1=10
    can.create_line(apple_x1,apple_y1,apple_x1,apple_y1,width=10,fill="red")


window.bind("w",move_up)
window.bind("s",move_down)
window.bind("a",move_left)
window.bind("d",move_right)
window.bind("<Up>",apple_make)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can move objects on a canvas, instead of deleting and recreating them?

Comment: I'm not aware of this. How do you do it?

Comment: It's all documented. You can use the canvas's `move` or `coords` methods.

Comment: beside that, check the `create_line` method inside `apple_make`, you are drawing invisible points by using the same coordinates for the head and tail of the line